# wxWidgets with MinGW, "wx/wx.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, mingw, wxwidgets

I am new to C++ and wxWidgets. During the last couple of days, I have followed a tutorial with Visual Studio into how to build wxWidgets desktop applications (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOIbK4bJKS8&t=800s).

Now, because I am not familiar with Visual Studio, I wanted to move to edit the code with Atom and compile with MinGW from Windows command prompt.

The app has the following files:

```
cMake.h
AnalogRead.h
cMake.cpp
AnalogRead.cpp
```

In Visual Studio, you need to include two directories and one library in the project, which are the following:
Paths:

```
/wxWidgets/include
/wxWidgets/include/msvc
```

Libraries:

```
/wxWidgets/lib/vc_lib
```

Relative to the path where the the C++ code is.

So I have tried to create the compile line, without success:

```
c++ -I/wxWidgets/include -I/wxWidgets/include/msvc -L/wxWidgets/lib/vc_lib cMake.cpp AnalogRead.cpp -o test
```

But I get the following error:

```
In file included from AnalogRead.cpp:1:0:
AnalogRead.h:3:19: fatal error: wx/wx.h: No such file or directory
 #include <wx/wx.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

The thing is, I am including that path in the compilation. wx/wx.h is inside the path /wxWidgets/include/.

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the community edition of Visual Studio is free you could just download it instead of using a compiler which has been ported from Linux to Windows. Your problems do seem to be caused by the differences in Windows and Linux paths.

Comment: It also makes no sense to be using header files in `/wxWidgets/include/msvc` unless your compiler really is Visual Studio.

Comment: I did compile wxWidgets in Visual Studio. I did not know there were going to be differences in the directories respect to compilation in the command line. I guess I will have to stick to Visual Studio for now to avoid errors.

Comment: If you compiled wxWidgets with Visual Studio then you have no choice but to use Visual Studio for your main program as well. You cannot mix and match compilers like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compile the library with one compiler and then compile the application using it with another, this is just not going to work. You should decide which compiler you want to use (or maybe try using both of them, but not both at the same time!) and follow the official build instructions in the file [docs/msw/install.md](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.4/docs/msw/install.md).

Answer (score 2):

`/wxWidgets/include` is not a relative path. This is an absolute path in the current disk. Do you have `C:\wxWidgets\include`? Try `-IwxWidgets/include` or `-I./wxWidgets/include`, without the leading /. This path should work if you have the wxWidgets directory in your app sources.

Comment: That does make it work but then another error comes up from the setup.h file: " fatal error: ../../../lib/vc_lib /msw /wx/setup.h: No such file or directory". I guess that is because I compiled wxWidgets in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use MinGW, you need to build the library with MinGW compiler and then use EXACTLY THE SAME command to buid your software.

Or use an IDE (CodeBlocks, CodeLite).

HTH.